# Javascript: Controlling an image's moving speed

Tags: javascript, image, move

I'm a beginner and currently I can move an image from left to right and I can turn it back to its initial point when moving finishes. What I want to do is also controlling image's speed. In order to do this I tried the codes below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userWidth = window.screen.width;

    function moveRight(speed) {
        var pp = document.getElementById("myimage");
        var lft = parseInt(pp.style.left);
        var tim = setTimeout("moveRight()", speed);
        lft = lft + 50;
        pp.style.left = lft + "px"
        if (lft > (userWidth) + 80) {
            document.getElementById("myimage").style.left = 100 + "px";
            clearTimeout(tim);
        }

    }
</script>
```

And html:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Speed 1" onclick="moveRight(50)"  />
    <input type="button" value="Speed 2" onclick="moveRight(25)"  />
    <input type="button" value="Speed 3" onclick="moveRight(10)" />
</form>
```

**My problem:** there is no difference when I click any of three buttons. Image is always moving with the same speed and looks like buttons have no control on the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your above code doesn't have any speed logic. The only thing you're doing is delaying the time before the animation start :

```
var tim = setTimeout("moveRight()", speed);
```

Making a recursive call to a function waiting for an attribute (speed), is also a nogo.

I setted up a quick fiddle to demonstrate jquery animation speed :

http://jsfiddle.net/yeQtB/

To achieve speed in animation, two possibilities :

• Cycle logic :
You admit that rather than seconds, you can work with cycles, then just create a for loop, that will iterate until animation is over. **edit :** this is just here for the sake of the explanation

• Time logic
You have a distance and a timeframe (in sec), divide the distance by the timeframe, it gives you step, divide the distance by the step, it will give you the number of steps, then it is just a matter of creating a settimeout firing every second in a loop. **edit :** if you achieved this and is eager to go for something a bit smoother, i'd advise to have a look at the requestAnimationFrame HTML5 Api :

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you did in your orignal code is that when you call the function again you do not pass it the value of speed which means that the only thing that happens is that the first animation is delayed.

Try replacing the call with this line and then your code should work.

```
var tim = setTimeout("moveRight("+speed+")", speed);
```

With this you can still do this without using Jquery

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the variable `speed` to `moveRight` in the `setTimeout` :

```
var userWidth = window.screen.width,
    tim,
    pp = document.getElementById("myimage"); // You should cache your variables

function moveRight(speed) {
    var lft = parseInt(pp.style.left) || 0;

    tim = setTimeout("moveRight(" + speed + ")"); // Here you have to pass speed as a parameter
    lft = lft + speed; // Here I guess it is speed rather than 50
    pp.style.left = lft + "px"
    if (lft > (userWidth) + 80) {
        pp.style.left = 100 + "px";
        clearTimeout(tim);
    }
}
```